# OOM when collecting small result set from Pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, out-of-memory, collect

I'm currently having some issues when collecting results when running ~100 aggregations on parquet data.

What I've currently done is to run the aggregation for each stat and then `join` that result onto a result DataFrame. So at the end of all my calculations, this result DataFrame will have ~100 or so entries in it all in 1 row.

My issue right now is that I'm running Spark locally and when I run a spark action to get my results (`collect()` or `head()`) I'm getting OOM errors. I've read a lot about not collecting on the driver but in this case the resultant DataFrame is extremely small and I'm running this on files that might only be 1gb in size or smaller with 16gb of driver memory. Is there another way I should be getting these results?

I've also tried batching stats but it doesn't seem to tremendously help this issue.

Any help is appreciated, thanks!

EDIT: file is 100MB when compressed in Parquet

Comment: Parquet's compression rate is [quite impressive](https://blog.cloudera.com/benchmarking-apache-parquet-the-allstate-experience/), so 0.1Gb parquet might end up to 10G raw data, so you might want to increase driver memory to somewhat larger than that

Answer (score 0):

Well you are right you should not use collect(), the 1 GB data you see will have  much higher memory footprint once it gets into the memory because data would be deserialized.

You can try :-

1. Print the data, instead of collecting it.
2. Increase the driver memory.
3. Write it to disk.

Comment: Ah sorry to clarify, that was my original file size so compressed in parquet it amounts to around 100MB